# How do I understand this dump that fails on Sleep()

Tags: c++, debugging, dump

Ok, I'm confused why this debug shows me this line as the failure.

Call stack

```
[External Code]
WorkLoop.cpp
[External Code]
```

Code in WorkLoop.cpp

```
while(doneWithWork == FALSE)
{
    if (threadsStatusesGood() == FALSE) 
    {
       logErrorMessage("Tread failed");
       doneWithWork = TRUE;
    }
    if (doneWithWork ==FALSE)
    {
        while (timeSpanNotToCheckIfDoneWithWork())
        {
            if (SystemStatusGood() == TRUE)
            {
                if ((shouldDoStuff == FALSE) &&
                     WaitFoMoreWork() == OAS_FALSE))
                {
                    shouldDoStuff = TRUE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                shouldDoStuff = FALSE;
            }

            Sleep(100);
=>      } // debug pointer on this line.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any description of the failure in your post. How are we supposed to tell you what's wrong if we don't even know what the failure is?

Comment: Ah, there's a thread dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't actually clarify about your exact failure, but I'd suspect an asynchronous operation (background thread) had been pulled into execution as soon

```
Sleep(100);
```

was called, and caused an exception. If you don't have debuggable `[External Code]` the least point of capture will be your own code.

Comment: this question and answer is useful.
I know I'm going to have this brainfart again, so I'll keep it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be you fall in another thread, while this thread sleep?

Comment: I think that's the reason, yes.